# 2d floor plan (image) dataset for ML

Tags: annotations

Im looking for 2d floor plan dataset for annotation, but cannot find the big dataset. I already found site 2d floor plan dataset, but here does not have a lot dataset. Will be good if find around 500 of 2d floor images(.jpg) [dataset](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fidler/projects/rent3D.html)

Answer (score 6):

There are 500 floor plans (in the form of images) available here:
https://rit.rakuten.co.jp/data_release/

You need to make an application to get access to them.

Additionally, I've seen some open data-sets here:

- http://dag.cvc.uab.es/resources/floorplans/
- https://github.com/gesstalt/ROBIN/blob/master/ROBIN.zip
- http://mathieu.delalandre.free.fr/projects/sesyd/symbols/floorplans.html
- https://www.kaggle.com/finlay/renthop-image-extract-floorplan-img/data

Good luck!

Comment: I know it is a long shot. But, do you happen to know any dataset which has electrical floor plans ?